# Finding continuous subarray in ArrayList java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java, and I'm practicing. I'm writing a program to find all continuous subarrays in a given array of integers. For simplicity, I insert the input from the keyboard (each number in new line) and the indication for the end of the array is a negative integer.

I fill the array using this method:

```
public static void main(String []args){
        // allocate new array       
        ArrayList<Integer> inputArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        
        int number = 0;
        while(number >= 0) {
            
            // get input from user
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            number = input.nextInt();
            
            inputArray.add(number);     
        }

        // sort the array
        Collections.sort(inputArray);

       // remove the negative integer (which is stored in the first cell of the array)
       inputArray.remove(0);

        // allocate new array to store the sequence
        ArrayList<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        // get first cluster
        sequence = FindSequence(0, input);

        for(int it : sequence){
            System.out.println(it);

        }
}
```

Up until here, everything works as expected.

At last, I'm trying to use this method to find the first sequence of continuous integers, it's not exactly my goal, but I'm starting from something more simple and then I'll progress and use this method to find all continuous sequences:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> FindSequence(int index, ArrayList<Integer> input) {
    ArrayList<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while(input.get(index) == input.get(index + 1) || input.get(index) == input.get(index + 1) + 1 ) {
        sequence.add(input.get(index));
        index++;
    }
    
    sequence.add(input.get(index));

    for(int it : sequence) {
            System.out.println(it);
    }
    
    return sequence;
}
```

Both methods are declared and implemented in the same class.

The problem is that the sequence I enter is `1 2 3 -1` I expect  `1 2 3` to be the printed but all that I get as output is `1`.
I've tried debugging a bit using prints - and I discovered that the program doesn't enter the while loop, although the condition is satisfied, since `input.get(index) = 1` and `input.get(index + 1) = 2` so `input.get(index) == input.get(index + 1) + 1`  is true.

The operator `||` means (as far as I know) boolean or, so only one of the conditions must be satisfied in order for the program to enter the while loop. I'm really confused, and I have no idea why this is happening, perhaps someone could explain and advice me on how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: With what index value are you calling your findSequence method?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the line when I was copying the code, I'll edit this. I'm calling it with index 0

Comment: Also you might want to try using come brackets here (input.get(index + 1) + 1)

Comment: @Vladimir I've tried adding brackets, didn't help :\

Comment: Should it be `input.get(index) + 1 == input.get(index + 1)`. I changed the positon of +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line `input.get(index) == input.get(index + 1) + 1` you want to check that the next index is 1 greater than the current one.

To check the same, after adding 1 to the current element it should equal the next one. The boolean statement for the same can be

```
input.get(index) + 1 == input.get(index + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is a bit wrong, since the next element should be equal to the predecessor + 1
It should look like this :

```
while(input.get(index) == input.get(index + 1) || (input.get(index) + 1) == input.get(index + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the condition check that you are using, that violates the entire purpose of finding the continuous series. The below code works fine.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class GFG {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(-1);
    FindSequence(0,list);
 }

 public static ArrayList<Integer> FindSequence(int index, ArrayList<Integer> input) {
  ArrayList<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  while(input.get(index) == input.get(index + 1) || input.get(index) + 1 == input.get(index + 1)) {
    sequence.add(input.get(index));
    index++;
 }

  sequence.add(input.get(index));

  for(int it : sequence) {
        System.out.println(it);
  }
  return sequence;
 }
}
```